# Operations on tabular data text file using awk

Tags: awk, tabular

I'm producing a long tabular text file by extracting information from a set of log files. I wanted to do some operations on the resulting tabular data and create a new text file with tabular data.

My tabular data looks like this

```
Compound    State       Method      Approach    Energy
C(CCH)2         singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-CC-s.out
C(CCH)2         singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    -191.426232325854   3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-s.out
C(CCH)2         triplet     CC          Triplet orbs    -191.434509836762   3-1/C-CCH-2/C-CCH-2-t.out
C(NH2)2         triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/C-NH2-2/C-NH2-2-t.out
C(NMe2)2        triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/C-NMe2-2/C-NMe2-2-t.out
C(SH)2          singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-CC-s.out
C(SH)2          singlet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -835.261598037781   3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-s.out
C(SH)2          triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -835.190581480918   3-1/C-SH-2/C-SH-2-t.out
C(SiH3)2        singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/C-SiH3-2/C-SiH3-2-CC-s.out
C(SiH3)2        singlet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -620.339326760127   3-1/C-SiH3-2/C-SiH3-2-s.out
C(SiH3)2        triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -620.379515709604   3-1/C-SiH3-2/C-SiH3-2-t.out
CF2             singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/CF2/CF2-CC-s.out
CF2             singlet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -237.686609290184   3-1/CF2/CF2-s.out
CF2             triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -237.601091999318   3-1/CF2/CF2-t.out
CF2C            singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    not converged or error  3-1/CF2C/CF2C-CC-s.out
CF2C            singlet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -275.668206445318   3-1/CF2C/CF2C-s.out
CF2C            triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -275.641632193745   3-1/CF2C/CF2C-t.out
CH2             singlet     CC          Triplet orbs    -39.061384267881    3-1/CH2/CH2-CC-s.out
CH2             singlet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -39.109884610315    3-1/CH2/CH2-s.out
CH2             triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -39.129586138474    3-1/CH2/CH2-t.out
```

and the code producing it is as below:

```
awk '
BEGIN           {print "Compound\tState\t\tMethod\t\tApproach\tEnergy"}'
find . -name '*.out' | while read FILENAME

do

awk '
FNR==1          {if (FILENAME ~ /-/) 
                  { sub("./","", FILENAME);m=split(FILENAME, Ti, "/") 
                             n=split(Ti[m], T, "-")
                             if (length(T[1]) < 2 ) {T[1]=T[1]"("T[2]")"substr(T[3],1,1)}
                             printf("%-15.10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t",  T[1], substr(T[n],1,1)=="t"?"triplet":"singlet", FILENAME~"-CC"?"CC":"DFT",FILENAME~"3-1"?"Triplet orbs":"NONE");
                             FOUND=0
                 }
                 else
                  {sub("./","", FILENAME);m=split(FILENAME, Ti, "/") 
                             n=split(Ti[m], T, ".")
                             if (length(T[1]) < 2 ) {T[1]=T[1]"("T[2]")"T[3]}
                             printf ("%-15.10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t", T[1] , "Singlet", "DFT",FILENAME~"3-1"?"Triplet orbs":"NONE");
                             FOUND=0
                }
                }
/HURRAY/        {FOUND=1; 
                }
FOUND &&
/^FINAL.*ERGY/  {print $NF " \t" FILENAME 
                 CONV=1
                }
END             {if (!CONV) print "not converged or error\t" FILENAME 
                };       
' OFS="\t" "$FILENAME"
done
```

I wanted to whenever columns: Compound, Method and Approach are a match energy values be reduced from each other exactly as Singlet-Triplet and form a new tabular data all together.
for example

```
CF2             singlet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -237.686609290184   3-1/CF2/CF2-s.out
CF2             triplet     DFT         Triplet orbs    -237.601091999318   3-1/CF2/CF2-t.out
```

Form one row as

```
CF2             DFT         Triplet orbs    0.085517290866
```

and of course if match is not found just a simple error match not found or data not available.
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't attempt to read your awk script but assuming that you start with the data listed above

```
awk -vOFS="\t" -f m.awk data
```

will generate

```
C(CCH)2     CC      Triplet orbs    -0.00827751
C(SH)2      DFT     Triplet orbs    0.0710166
C(SiH3)2    DFT     Triplet orbs    -0.0401889
CF2 DFT     Triplet orbs    0.0855173
CF2C        DFT     Triplet orbs    0.0265743
CH2 DFT     Triplet orbs    -0.0197015
```

here is the script

```
 $ cat m.awk
    {
      k = $1 OFS $3 OFS $4
    }
    $2 ~ /singlet/  {
      if ($6 = $6 + 0) {
        if (k in t) {
          print k, $5, t[k] - $6
          t[k] = ""
        } else {
          s[k] = $6
        }
      }
    }

    $2 ~ /triplet/  {
      if ($6 = $6 + 0) {
        if (k in s) {
          print k, $5, $6 - s[k]
          s[k] = ""
        } else {
          t[k] = $6
        }
      }
    }
```

Explanation: construct key from fields 1,3,4.  Try to match singlet and triple pairs when the value is a number.  When a pair is used, invalidate the used value.

We can extract the common logic to a function to further simply the code

```
  function pairup(t,s,sign) {
    if ($6 = $6 + 0) {
      if (k in t) {
        print k, $5, sign*(t[k] - $6)
        delete t[k]
      } else {
        s[k] = $6
      }
    }
  }

 {k = $1 OFS $3 OFS $4}

 $2 ~ /singlet/{pairup(t,s,1)}

 $2 ~ /triplet/{pairup(s,t,-1)}
```

I think you can further simplify by reducing to use of a single array, but don't have time work on it.

Comment: sorry for being a noob, that last part gives me ": k: command not found", is that an awk function? it doesn't look like bash?